# Matlab - z(x:y) - vectoring is not working

Tags: matlab

vectoring is not working

```
z = 10:-1:1;

x = 1:9;

y = 2:10;

z(x:y)
```

ans =

```
10  9
```

No vectorization index range?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: What is the issue? Your output is exactly as expected: `x:y` gives you `x(1):y(1)`, which is `1:2` here. Thus `z(1:2)` or rather `z([1 2])` gives you `[10 9]`.

Comment: x and y - vector. z (x) will give us a lot of values ​​of z.
I assumed that z (x: y) will give a lot of pairs of values ​​z.
why suddenly the vector X is transformed into X (1)?
If I need to x (1) - I did write - x (1).
If printed X - means it is necessary to use the entire vector X.

but I see that it is not. It seems to me that the logic is broken.
Sometimes X - is a vector. Sometimes X - is a number.

Comment: @user1940681 But `z(x:y)` just won't give you pairs and isn't intended to. If you want pairs, you'll have to ask "How do I get pairs?" instead of "Why doesn't it work?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pairs, you'll have to use

```
>> z([x; y])

ans =

    10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2
     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

resp.

```
>> z([x; y].')

ans =

    10     9
     9     8
     8     7
     7     6
     6     5
     5     4
     4     3
     3     2
     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks for help and clarifications !!!